How can I create a new prefix for an extended key (xprv, zprv...)?
I'm trying to create a new prefix to change the prefix of a xprv, but it doesn't work, what I need to know for do it? I'm looking to use the prefix 'nxprv'.
I'm trying to use this code(it works to zprv):
function convertXprvToNxprv(pub, prefix) {
  let payload = b58.decode(pub)
    , key = payload.slice(4)

  return b58.encode(Buffer.concat([Buffer.from(prefix,'hex'), key]))
}


I’m not familiar with 'nxprv', could you provide more information about the context in which you heard about that?

@Murch It doesn't exist yet, I want to create it.
